# How to find out which item on focus after scrolling the RecyclerView Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I get the position of a list item that's on focus after scrolling the RecyclerView? Will this work?

```
recyclerview1.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener())
```

If yes, then how?

Comment: To improve the chances to get a proper answer, I suggest you to always add 1) what you've tried so far, 2) a thorough description of the issue and 3) the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are two ways of doing this.

One using **onBindViewHolder** , in `onBindViewHolder` add

```
 Log.d("onBindViewHolder", "position =>"+position);
 count++; //for the position
```

but remember in this way count call several time for each news and you must count only in first call.

Other way around is using `layoutManagers` i.e `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager` by doing this

```
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

**OR** for `scrollListener` you can do this

```
recycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    //you can use other methods as per your requirements
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Scrolled to"+layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
})
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry but actually my question is 
if i scroll the view and that is showing 10th item of the list than it toast a 10 
if that is 50th item than 50

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this problem, and i got I put the recyclerView in scrollView So please never put the recyclerview inside the scrollView that may also cause mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() that always return a fixed value. and also check recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);